# Gradle: Conditional include of subprojects

Tags: gradle

I have a maven multi-module project (please see the attached image for the structure). I am in the process of migrating to Gradle.

[image: Project Structure]

We have multiple profiles inside AppBuild/pom.xml like shown below; and we run our maven build from AppBuild with `-P` option for the profiles.

[image: Profile Structure]

Since I am new to Gradle, I am not able to decide what is the best way to go about it. Now, I am thinking to put some conditional `include` in `settings.gradle` based on some `-P` argument, but I am not too sure. Could someone help me how to go about this? What is the best way with some examples.

Thanks in advance.

~ Niranjan

Comment: a non gradle way to solve this: make some alternate settings.gradle files, then some scripts to move them around as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across the same question, since I have a multiproject build where I want to include a special subproject only on some occasions.

This special subproject only depends on one other subproject and takes approx 1-2min to configure. So I don't want to have it included if I don't want to build it. That saves some build time.
So, what I did was to modify the `settings.gradle`

```
if(file('MySpecialProject').exists()){
  include ':MySpecialProject'
}
```

When I do not want to build `MySpecialProject` I can simply rename/delete its folder. In my case, the folder is a symlink, since this 'subproject' resides in it's own git repo.
Even if *@spy* writes that if/then/else is not possible in settings, it did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional include isn't straightforward in Gradle (it's not a first-class feature), and it's unclear why you would need it for so few subprojects. I recommend to start without and add all four subprojects to `settings.gradle`.

Comment: Hi Peter, For an example I showed few, my original project has 15 subfolders within `AppBuild` folder and we generate 6 different artifacts out of those (4 web app WARs, 2 TAR files). And, we don't want always to run all the build; hence, with maven we added several profiles with requiring modules. Since, the directive is to move to Gradle, we wanted similar feature. I was thinking to add `-P` with Gradle and based on that `include` required projects. Appreciate if you could help us in providing another solution for this problem.

Comment: Gradle is smart enough to only rebuild what's required, hence you should be fine. I don't recommend to try and imitate Maven's conditional includes - it shouldn't be necessary for your number of projects, and it is difficult to implement well. If necessary, you can speed up the build further with `--parallel` and `--configuration-on-demand` (see [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for details).

Comment: i've got a similar use case and need to disable certain modules during specified build profiles. Another oversight with gradle. The normal if then else bits for module/build.gradle don't work and settings.gradle apparently doesn't support if-then-else structures.

Comment: This is not a straight answer. What if I want to build the subprojects conditionally. e.g gradle -Pinstall build, builds only my installer project and else all other. if (Project.hasProperty('install'))  in settings.gradle does not work

Comment: It is not straightforward in maven, so why making it difficult in gradle?